# How would I be able to keep a mob a certain distance away in a specific direction from the player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to teleport a villager exactly 6 blocks west of the player repeatedly. I have tried everything I can think of. How can I do this?

Comment: `I have tried everything I can think of` is pretty useless. Can you please edit your question so it contains exactly what commands you have tried? That way we can give you a better answer. Thanks!

Comment: that said, it is pretty clear what the user is asking. It might be broad, but the question makes logical sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a clock, teleport the villager to the player:

```
/tp @e[type=Villager] @p
```

And then, in the same tick, teleport the villager 6 blocks west:

```
/tp @e[type=Villager] ~6 ~ ~
```